# How to differentiate between three different flavours of pcap files?

Tags: windows, wireshark, pcap

There appears to be 3 different file formats associated with the ".pcap" extension -- libpcap /w microsecond timestamps, libpcap /w nanosecond timestamps, and pcapng.

Is there an easy way to differentiate between them that is scriptable?  Either cmd, powershell, or bash is acceptable.

Comment: Which flavor of OS?  Windows or Linux/Unix?

Comment: Preferably Windows, but if it works in cygwin that's good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the file type of pcap files with `capinfos` (e.g., simply enter `capinfos your_capture.pcap` in the command line).

`capinfos` is available with the WireShark distribution.